# How to unzip, zipped XML file in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, zip

I am developing an application in which I am getting a zipped XML file from web service.
Now I need to unzip it and I have to parse it. **How can I unzip an XML file coming from web service**??? Is it necessary to save unzipped file (after unzipping) before taking it to parse or is there a code which gives unzipped file directly without saving it to documents directory?

Code for this is helpful.

Thanks in advance..